# PerformanceCounter does not return values on some machines

Tags: c#, performance, counter, performancecounter

I'm using .NETs System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter class to retrieve memory usage and % CPU Time of a webservice process.

Running the code locally on my Win10 development machine, calling NextValue() returns the proper value. As soon as i move the binaries to a Windows Server 2012 machine, i get

- 0s for PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName)
- "mostly" 0s for PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total") (intermittently, i get proper values there, but only every 10th or so value actually has a number other than 0
- Completely bogus (and not-changing with actual usage) values for PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set", p.ProcessName) (in fact, that value remains at constant 44 MB over complete restarts of the application, regardless of load on the service.

There are no exceptions thrown indicating that i'm using the wrong counter names or process name.

Here's what i tried (with no success)

- checked for any "Disable Performance Monitor" Registry keys (none found)
- rebuilt performance counter settings using lodctr /R
- ran the application with elevated privileges
- added the user running the application to the "Performance Monitor Users" Group
- added the user running the application to the "Performance Log Users" Group
- ran Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(*)\% Processor Time" in Powershell -> got valid numbers on each call (but the first, which is ok)

What am i missing? Most of the answers relating to PerformanceCounters returning wrong values or 0 are related to NextValue being called only once, for example. This is not the case here (and that makes finding a solution somewhat tough). I'm very aware of that limitation and i don't expect the first value to be returned to be non-zero. It's all the other values following that are coming out wrong or 0.

Comment: Have you checked localization? If your Win server 2012 is non English, performance counters can fail. Also is there any exceptions?

Comment: You can also try to monitor counters values using Windows Performance Monitor tool, maybe there is problem with counters itself

Comment: No exceptions, unfortunately. I've actually considered localization to be an issue, so i replaced the counter names and process name with bogus values to see what would happen in that case, and it threw an exception crashing the application. None of that happened when i run the app on the server :(

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski i was able to read out the counters using powershell. so they seem to be working

Comment: Try to use `PdhLookupPerfNameByIndex` function to get an actual name of counter. Also _lodctr_ command can fail with rebuild cache, if you run it from wrong folder (system32 instead of syswow64 and vice versa). There is code snippet, which we use in case of counters fatal error

Comment: ```var lodctr =
       Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem
         ? Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86
         : Environment.SpecialFolder.System),
        "lodctr.exe");

      var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
      {
       FileName = lodctr,
       Arguments = "/R",
       Verb = "runas",
       UseShellExecute = true,
       CreateNoWindow = true,
       WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
      };```

Comment: Tried with PdhLookupPerfNameByIndex. Same thing (would using the wrong name not cause an exception anyways? I'm not getting exceptions. Just zeros and wrong values)

Comment: called lotctr both from syswow64 *and* system32. Both ran through successfully

Answer (score 1):

Here's what turned out to be the problem:

I originally "kinda" fixed it by restarting the server. This led me to believe that you'd have to restart after every call to lodctr which is *nonsense* (phew)
It just worked occasionally because of the order in which services were started on the server, i guess..

Turns out, that on the servers where it didn't work, there were multiple processes with the same executable name, which means that calling PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", *Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName*) get's you complete garbage.

Say you have three Services running, all using the same executable name "MyWebService.exe", but they may all be in a different location, use different configurations, etc., then you need to call the PerformanceCounter with an *InstanceName* of "MyWebService#1", "MyWebService#2", etc..

Of course it's somewhat tricky to find the right number to use after the #.
And what's infinitely worse: if someone kills MyWebService#1, the PerformanceCounters for MyWebService#2 will start monitoring the metrics for what used to be MyWebService#3 instead. And whatever is monitoring MyWebService#3 will get an Exception.

Great Idea from the .NET team. Instead of using Process *ID*s like a sane person, why not use Process names with a Suffix to *identify* processes instead o_O

So:

1. you need to update your PerformanceCounter.InstanceName regularly to make sure you still got the right process
2. you actually need another PerformanceCounter to *get* the right InstanceName, which turns out to be ridiculously slow.

search for "PerformanceCounter multiple Processes Name" for more helpful links

Thanks @PavelAnikhouski for your help nonetheless